# Update table and Insert into table issue in PHP

Tags: php, insert

I have to enter data in a table if I click on add link and I have to update existing data when I click on Edit link.

$_POST receives data in either condition. But based on weather its a EDIT (update) or Add(insert) my query should execute.

I am confused as to how I should do it.

This is the section of the code. (At present EDIT too runs the insert query as it always goes in else part)

```
if ($count==0)
    {
        if(mysql_query('SELECT SRNO from names where SRNO='.$SRNO) === true)

            //if($addval == 1)
            {
             mysql_query('update names set fname="'.$fname.'", lname="'.$lname.'", address="'.$address.'", comments="'.$comments.'", email="'.$email.'", phone="'.$phone.'"  where SRNO="'.$srno.'"');    
                     $addval=1;
            }
        else
           //if ($addval == 1)
             {
             mysql_query("INSERT INTO names (fname,lname,phone,email,comments,address) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname','$phone','$email','$comments','$address')");
             }
             header('Location:'.$page);
             }

       }
```

Complete code is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>List of users</title>
    </head>
<body>
    <?php
        $page='index.php';  
        $addval=6;

        mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die (mysql_error());
        mysql_select_db("list") or die (mysql_error());

        if (empty($_POST) === false)
        {
            $count=0;
            $fname= $_POST['fname'];
            $lname= $_POST['lname'];
            $srno=  $_POST['SRNO'];
            $address=$_POST['address'];
            $comments=$_POST['comments'];
            $email=$_POST['email'];
            $phone=$_POST['phone'];

                if (empty($lname) === true || empty($fname) === true || empty($address) === true || empty($comments) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($phone) === true) 
                {
                    echo '<h3>All fields are mandatory</h3>';

                }
                else
                {
                        if (filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
                        {
                            echo '<h3>This is not a valid e-mail address.</h3><br />';
                            $count=$count+1;
                        }
                        if (ctype_alpha($fname) === false || ctype_alpha($lname) === false)
                        {
                            echo '<h3>Name should contain character only!</h3><br />';
                            $count=$count+1;
                        }
                        if( !is_numeric($phone) ) 
                        {
                                echo '<h3>Please enter a valid phone number</h3><br />';
                                $count=$count+1;
                        }
                        if ($count==0)
                        {
                            if(mysql_query('SELECT SRNO from names where SRNO='.$SRNO) === true)

                            //if($addval == 1)
                            {
                                mysql_query('update names set fname="'.$fname.'", lname="'.$lname.'", address="'.$address.'", comments="'.$comments.'", email="'.$email.'", phone="'.$phone.'"  where SRNO="'.$srno.'"');   
                                $addval=1;
                            }
                            else
                            //if ($addval == 1)
                            {
                                mysql_query("INSERT INTO names (fname,lname,phone,email,comments,address) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname','$phone','$email','$comments','$address')");
                            }
                            header('Location:'.$page);
                        }

                }
        }

        if(isset($_GET['delete']))
        {

            mysql_query('DELETE from names where SRNO='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['delete']));
            header('Location:'.$page);
        }

        if(isset($_GET['edit']))
        {
            $getedit=mysql_query('SELECT SRNO, fname, lname, phone, email, address, comments from names where SRNO='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['edit']));

            echo '<table border=0>';
            while ($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getedit))
                {
                    echo '<form method="POST" action="">';

                    echo '<tr><td>Sr.No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['SRNO'].' name="SRNO" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['fname'].' name="fname"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['lname'].' name="lname"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Phone No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['phone'].' name="phone"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>E-mail address:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['email'].' name="email"</td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea name="address" rows=4>'.$get_row['address'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Comments:</td><td><textarea name="comments" rows=4>'.$get_row['comments'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"></td><td><a href="index.php">Cancel</a></td></tr>';
                    echo '</form>';                                 
                }
            echo '</table>';

        }

        if(isset($_GET['add']))
        {
            echo '<table border=0>';

                    echo '<form method="POST" action="">';

                    echo '<tr><td>Sr.No:</td><td><input type="text"  name="SRNO" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text"  name="fname"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text"  name="lname"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Phone No:</td><td><input type="text"  name="phone"></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>E-mail address:</td><td><input type="text"  name="email"</td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea name="address" rows=4></textarea></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td>Comments:</td><td><textarea name="comments" rows=4></textarea></td></tr>';
                    echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"></td><td><a href="index.php">Cancel</a></td></tr>';
                    echo '</form>';                                 

            echo '</table>';


        }

        echo '<a href=index.php?add=add>Add new entry...</a>';

        $get=mysql_query('SELECT  SRNO, fname, lname, email, phone, address, comments from names ORDER BY SRNO ASC');

        if (mysql_num_rows($get)==0)
        {
            echo 'There are no entries';
        }
            else
        {
            echo '<table border=0 cellspacing=25 cellpadding=1>';
            echo'<tr><th>Sr. No</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone No</th><th>E-mail</th><th>Address</th><th>Comments!!</th><th>Modify</th><th>Delete!</th></tr>';      
            while($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
                {
                    echo '<tr><td>'.$get_row['SRNO'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['fname'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['lname'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['phone'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['email'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['address'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['comments'].'</td><td><a href="index.php?edit='.$get_row['SRNO'].'">Edit</a></td><td><a href="index.php?delete='.$get_row['SRNO'].'">Delete</a></td></tr>';

                }
            echo '</table>';
        }       
    ?>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Please do not use mysql_* functions. They've been deprecated.

Comment: Ok. Rachel. Thanks. I removed that part. :D

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have tried to modify the code ... Hope this help .. please try

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>List of users</title>
  </head>
<body>

   <?php
       $page='index.php';  
       $addval=6;

    mysql_connect("localhost","root","welcome") or die (mysql_error());
    //mysql_select_db("list") or die (mysql_error());

    if (empty($_POST) === false)
    {
        $count=0;
        $fname= $_POST['fname'];
        $lname= $_POST['lname'];
        $srno=  $_POST['SRNO'];
        $address=$_POST['address'];
        $comments=$_POST['comments'];
        $email=$_POST['email'];
        $phone=$_POST['phone'];

            if (empty($lname) === true || empty($fname) === true || empty($address) === true || empty($comments) === true || empty($email) === true || empty($phone) === true) 
            {
                echo '<h3>All fields are mandatory</h3>';

            }
            else
            {
                    if (filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false)
                    {
                        echo '<h3>This is not a valid e-mail address.</h3><br />';
                        $count=$count+1;
                    }
                    if (ctype_alpha($fname) === false || ctype_alpha($lname) === false)
                    {
                        echo '<h3>Name should contain character only!</h3><br />';
                        $count=$count+1;
                    }
                    if( !is_numeric($phone) ) 
                    {
                            echo '<h3>Please enter a valid phone number</h3><br />';
                            $count=$count+1;
                    }
                    if ($count==0)
                    {
                        if(mysql_query('SELECT SRNO from names where SRNO='.$SRNO) === true)
                      // condition for update
                        if(isset($_GET['edit']))
                        {
                            mysql_query('update names set fname="'.$fname.'", lname="'.$lname.'", address="'.$address.'", comments="'.$comments.'", email="'.$email.'", phone="'.$phone.'"  where SRNO="'.$srno.'"');   
                            $addval=1;
                        }
             //condition for add  
                        else if(isset($_GET['add']))
                        {
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO names (fname,lname,phone,email,comments,address) VALUES ('$fname', '$lname','$phone','$email','$comments','$address')");
                        }
                        header('Location:'.$page);
                    }

            }
    }

    if(isset($_GET['delete']))
    {

        mysql_query('DELETE from names where SRNO='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['delete']));
        header('Location:'.$page);
    }

    if(isset($_GET['edit']))
    {
        $getedit=mysql_query('SELECT SRNO, fname, lname, phone, email, address, comments from names where SRNO='.mysql_real_escape_string((int)$_GET['edit']));

        echo '<table border=0>';
        while ($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($getedit))
            {
                echo '<form method="POST" action="">';

                echo '<tr><td>Sr.No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['SRNO'].' name="SRNO" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['fname'].' name="fname"></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['lname'].' name="lname"></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>Phone No:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['phone'].' name="phone"></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>E-mail address:</td><td><input type="text" value='.$get_row['email'].' name="email"</td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea name="address" rows=4>'.$get_row['address'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>Comments:</td><td><textarea name="comments" rows=4>'.$get_row['comments'].'</textarea></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"></td><td><a href="index.php">Cancel</a></td></tr>';
                echo '</form>';                                 
            }
        echo '</table>';

    }

    if(isset($_GET['add']))
    {
        echo '<table border=0>';

                echo '<form method="POST" action="">';

                echo '<tr><td>Sr.No:</td><td><input type="text"  name="SRNO" readonly="readonly"></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>First Name:</td><td><input type="text"  name="fname"></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>Last Name:</td><td><input type="text"  name="lname"></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>Phone No:</td><td><input type="text"  name="phone"></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>E-mail address:</td><td><input type="text"  name="email"</td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>Address:</td><td><textarea name="address" rows=4></textarea></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td>Comments:</td><td><textarea name="comments" rows=4></textarea></td></tr>';
                echo '<tr><td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="save"></td><td><a href="index.php">Cancel</a></td></tr>';
                echo '</form>';                                 

        echo '</table>';


    }

    echo '<a href=index.php?add=add>Add new entry...</a>';

    $get=mysql_query('SELECT  SRNO, fname, lname, email, phone, address, comments from names ORDER BY SRNO ASC');

    if (mysql_num_rows($get)==0)
    {
        echo 'There are no entries';
    }
        else
    {
        echo '<table border=0 cellspacing=25 cellpadding=1>';
        echo'<tr><th>Sr. No</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Phone No</th><th>E-mail</th><th>Address</th><th>Comments!!</th><th>Modify</th><th>Delete!</th></tr>';      
        while($get_row=mysql_fetch_assoc($get))
            {
                echo '<tr><td>'.$get_row['SRNO'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['fname'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['lname'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['phone'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['email'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['address'].'</td><td>'.$get_row['comments'].'</td><td><a href="index.php?edit='.$get_row['SRNO'].'">Edit</a></td><td><a href="index.php?delete='.$get_row['SRNO'].'">Delete</a></td></tr>';

            }
        echo '</table>';
    }       
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I added the two if statements you changed.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (mysql_query('SELECT SRNO from names where SRNO='.$SRNO) === true)
```

is wrong way for checking a value against database.
please read the manual entry for [mysql_query()](http://php.net/mysql_query) to see what does actually return this function

Not to mention that your code is wide open to SQL injection

Also, you have to turn error reporting on, to be notified of all the typos in the variable names:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

at the top of all your scripts